# Story about a girl who saves Merlin

Tags: story-identification

I came across this story roughly 10-15 years ago (might be older), the story is about a teenage girl (high school age) named Vivian (or Vivien/Vivianne, not sure about the spelling) who loves to explore the surroundings of her house and comes across a fairy circle and meets a group of fairies. These fairies ask for her help to perform several tasks which are all very important.

The tasks that I can remember (vaguely)

1. Save a boy (maybe an orphan or just an unloved boy) from something bad (again not sure exactly what happens but know her task was to save him).
2. Help this boy recognize his power (he is actually Merlin from the Arthurian legends)
3. Hand a sword through a lake to an unknown person (only her hand goes through the water to become the Lady of the Lake)

Her reward for doing all of these is to spend the rest of her life with Merlin who returns to her an old man after doing whatever he had been doing. He later tells her that all he wanted was to be with her but the fairies told him that he had to reach the height of his power before he would be allowed to see Vivian again.

When she dies at an old age, she suddenly wakes up, finding that it was all a dream. She goes home and the next day at school, she finds the same boy she rescued all that time ago (in her dream) and the boy, Merlin recognizes her also.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Did you read this in an anthology, a magazine, or online?

Comment: Hey! I honestly do not remember as it was so long ago. Its possible it was an online story because I was an avid online reader back then.

Comment: Possibly not helping is that Vivian (or Vivien or a few other spellings) is one of the traditional names for the Lady of the Lake, also sometimes used for the enchantress who raised him, or the one who sealed him away in a tree or the cave.